# Sudo error, setuid

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I run some command series on Terminal. But at one time I ran

```
sudo chmod 777 /usr/bin/ -R
```

And giving some permissions on this directory. After that, I'm continue my work, and I got this message:

```
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo, owned by 0 users identity and should be setuid  bit set
```

I'm new on Ubuntu, what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to start by getting root write access to `/usr/bin/`. You'll need recovery mode or even a Live CD/USB. [Both those approaches are covered here](https://askubuntu.com/a/435347/449) — just ignore the password setting bit.

By this point you should be logged in as root.

Anyway fixing this isn't *too* hard because most of the files are straight 755 and there are only a handful of exceptions. So we'll start by setting everything in there to 755 and correct the exceptions. This is based off my filesystem so I've probably got a few things you don't but running `chmod` on a non-existent file shouldn't hurt.

```
chmod 755 /usr/bin/*

chmod 4755 /usr/bin/{{lp,g,}passwd,chfn,mtr,beep,traceroute6.iputils,pkexec,sudo,newgrp,ksu,chsh}
chmod 6755 /usr/bin/{X,at}
chmod 2755 /usr/bin/{mail-{un,touch,}lock,ssh-agent,mutt_dotlock,chage,bsd-write,wall,screen,crontab,mlocate,expiry,dotlockfile}

chmod 0755 /usr/bin/
```

This syntax is *exact*. You need to make sure it's entered correctly or it could break even more.

---

You could argue that this is too much to manually copy and paste. You might be right. We can handle the most important things and then reboot back into a graphical desktop to do the rest with `sudo`:

```
chmod 755 /usr/bin/*

chmod 4755 /usr/bin/{sudo,pkexec}
chmod 2755 /usr/bin/crontab
chmod 6755 /usr/bin/X

chmod 0755 /usr/bin/
```

---

For anybody curious on how to generate a list like that, here are the commands:

```
find /usr/bin -type f ! -perm 755 -printf '%m %P\n'
```

That does only look at files but all the links I could find linked back through to `/usr/bin/` files so they were already being dealt with.

Comment: but the sudo is gonna still broken so he just should boot from cd/usb then repair

Comment: @hwez Yeah I thought the permissions being changed to 777 would let them change the permissiosn without sudo but I've just tested that on a Live ISO in Virtualbox and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: He will need to set the `setuid` bit for that. There is a `super` package that provides a command to do that, but he will need to `su` to root, install that etc. Probably better to boot from Live media and repair.

Comment: I tried it on my own os

Answer (score 1):

There's no solution for this bug at this moment because there no root user in ubuntu Linux os, what I'm trying to say is that issues is impossible to solve , 'you need the root access to give permission' , 'ubuntu root access by sudo' , 'sudo is broken' so you can't solve sudo when it doesn't work ,'su' command needs a root user, when you try give 755 permission with live CD/USB to the /usr/bin folder you'll need root access, when you use ' $ sudo ' it gonna use the the sudo off the bed wich we're trying to solve 
there's only 1 solution for this witch is the issue that we're trying to fix. 
 and you can fix this issue by 're-install' boot CD/USB of the ubuntu , then in the installation type you have to choose update ubuntu then continue the installation .
 if you ask why Ubuntu haven't made a root user it's for security , wich is make ubuntu secured better then some Linux os, if you asks why the root user isn't secured ?
the answer is gonna be : if someone got your root password & ssh port is on he gonna make a bigger issues then the one that we have